# Как обойти ограничение primary_key в SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Столкнулся с такой бедой в алхимии: не дает создавать зависимости без  **primary_key**

Для наглядности (опустим опустил остальные поля), SQLAlchemy не даст создать таблицу **Color_figure**:

```
class Colors(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "colors"
    id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = _db.Column(_db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"table colors: {self.id}, {self.name}"

class Figures(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "figures"
    id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = _db.Column(_db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"table figures: {self.id}, {self.name}"


class Color_figure(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "color_figure"
    colors_id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, _db.ForeignKey('colors.id'))
    figures_id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, _db.ForeignKey('figures.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"table color_figure : {self.category_id}, {self.presentation_id}"
```

Да, понимаю, что можно организовать например так:

```
class Colors(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "colors"
    id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = _db.Column(_db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"table colors: {self.id}, {self.name}"

class Figures(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "figures"
    id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = _db.Column(_db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    colors_id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, _db.ForeignKey('colors.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"table figures: {self.id}, {self.name}"
```

Но это как-то неправильно смотрится, т.к. получается, что таблица начинает расти горизонтально + если есть записи в БД, то тогда надо будет добавлять искусcтвено поле и делать его :

```
nullable=False
```

Кто подскажет, если сталкивался с такой проблемой, то что получается, что ничего поделать нельзя и придется горизонтально растить таблицу **Figures**?

*UPD:*

**Предполагается, что каждая фигура может иметь только один цвет, т.е. отношение 1:1**

**UPD 2**

Еще такой вариант реализации, можно реализовать:

```
class Color_figure(_db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "color_figure"
    colors_id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    figures_id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Но в таком случает целостность данных не будет контролироваться, например можно легко удалить запись о цвете или фигуре, и SQLAlchemy ругаться не будет...

Comment: так а что вам мешает создать primary_key в модели Color_figure? и как вы вообще представляете себе таблицу без первичного ключа?

Comment: @strawdog, если создать primary_key  в этой таблице, то записи будут не уникальными

Comment: Создать композитный первичный ключ из обеих колонок? (не в курсе, умеет ли sqlalchemy такое)

Comment: *Предполагается, что каждая фигура может иметь только один цвет, т.е. отношение 1:1* Выглядит бредовато. Отношение 1:1 требует, чтобы один цвет к тому же был только у одной фигуры. Что вряд ли верно. А если неверно, и один и тот же цвет может быть у нескольких фигур, то в наличии имеется типичное 1:N. Т.е. цвет - это атрибут фигуры. И отдельная связующая таблица для такой связи нафиг не нужна.

Comment: @Akina, да на самом деле свойства и сущности другие, я это просто для примера и понимания таблицы написал. В теории вообще мог бы написать как создать связь 1:1 в SQLAlchemy без горизонтального расширения, но тогда бы никто ничего не понял...

Comment: Связь 1:1 создаётся элементарно. В основной таблице, как обычно, ключевое либо уникальное поле. В подчинённой таблице - ссылающееся поле (пока получилось 1:N), но ещё на это поле дополнительно накладывается требование уникальности. Вот и всё.

Comment: Просто если реализовать чистое, так сказать теоретическое, симметричное, 1:1, когда А имеет внешний ключ на Б, а Б соответственно внешний ключ на А - получится система, в которую нельзя вставить записи. Ибо вставка выполняется сперва в одну таблицу, и только потом в другую - а первая вставка обломается по причине отсутствия ссылочной записи.

Comment: @Akina, а как тогда вот это реализуют: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html#:~:text=CREATE%20TABLE%20my_association%20(%0A%20%20user_id%20INTEGER%20REFERENCES%20user(id)%2C%0A%20%20account_id%20INTEGER%20REFERENCES%20account(id)%2C%0A%20%20PRIMARY%20KEY%20(user_id%2C%20account_id)%0A)

Comment: Что-то я по ссылке про 1:1 ни полслова не нашёл.

Comment: @Akina, да, там M:M (но думаю, если бы они там указали, что записи уникальны обе, то получилось бы 1:1), но суть не в этом, а в том, что там же задали ссылки и нет никаких дополнительных полей, или я не правильно что-то понимаю?

Comment: *или я не правильно что-то понимаю?* Ну первичный ключ там в таблице имеется же. Композитный. Так что всё в порядке.

Comment: @Akina, а физически этот композитный ключ разве не состоит из ссылок? Или он получается таким же как у меня в **UPD 2**

Comment: *а физически этот композитный ключ разве не состоит из ссылок?* Если интересна физическая структура - следует обратиться к соответствующей документации. Однако скажу сразу. Если Вы мыслите так, что в мыслях используется слово "ссылка" - то Вы мыслите неправильно.